# subs {raster} function not working

Tags: r, dataframe, cell, raster, substitution

I have a raster layer with cell values 0, 0.9 and 1. I have a data frame with in the first column the cell ID and in the second column the value 0.936.(In the future these values in the second column could differ so I do need the specific cell to be replaced by the corresponding value in the data frame)

In Gen_raster I want to replace the cell values of cells matching the ID of new_values[1]with the values new_values[2].

I tried doing this with the subs() function (raster package), but for some reason the values new_values[1] do not match with the cell ID's of Gen_raster, therefore nothing happends with the cell values of Gen_raster.

I tried to use the subs() funtion for an example with similair characterisitcs( also using a raster layer and a data frame with two columns, int and num) and this does work. This is the code I used and the characteristics of the raster layer and the data frame:

```
Gen_raster1<-subs(Gen_raster, new_values, subsWithNA=FALSE)
```

Where Gen_raster:

```
    class       : RasterLayer 
    dimensions  : 401, 292, 117092  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
    extent      : -79.04166, -66.87499, -4.249997, 12.45834  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : NA 
    data source : in memory
    names       : layer 
    values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

and new_values:

```
     'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ id: int  7444 7446 7735 7745 8331 8924 9185 9473 13261 13554 ...
     $ v : num  0.936 0.936 0.936 0.936 0.936 ...
```

This is the example that I used and which did work:

```
    r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
    r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r)) * 10)
    df <- data.frame(id=2:8, v=c(10.003,10.03,11.006,11,12:14))
    x <- subs(r, df)
    x2 <- subs(r, df, subsWithNA=FALSE)
```

I do not see what the difference is between the two methods, and therefore I do not understand why the cell ID's of new_values and Gen_raster do not match..

Does anyone have suggestions? Would help me a lot.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subs` matches the cell values (0, 0.9, 1) in `Gen_raster`, with the first column (id) of `new_values`. It looks like there are no matches.

If I understand you well, what you are after is this:

```
Gen_raster[new_values$id] <- new_values$v
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thanks a lot for the help. But I do not get why in the example I give with raster layer r and dataframe df this method does exactly the same as the method you suggest, and when I try this for the rasterlayer Gen_raster  and the dataframe new_values this does not work...  Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: These are two rather different operations, one is substitution based on values, the other based on index.